# How can I exclude a class from LeakCanary?

Tags: android, leakcanary

I'm doing this:

```
ExcludedRefs excludedRefs = AndroidExcludedRefs.createAppDefaults()
                .clazz("androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment")
                .reason("Very annoying report fragment leak that isn't a leak apparently")
                .alwaysExclude()
                .build();
        LeakCanary
                .refWatcher(context)
                .listenerServiceClass(DisplayLeakService.class)
                .excludedRefs(excludedRefs)
                .watchDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .buildAndInstall();
```

And yet I'm still getting the `ReportFragment was never GCed but no leak found`.

I also get that for one of my activities, no I idea what to do about these `no leak found` messages.

Edit: current using LeakCanary 1.6.3

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778533/how-to-ignore-certain-classes-from-leakcanary

Comment: I'm actually starting to think I shouldn't be blocking that as that is just the class it is showing me but my `Activity` is extending it. My main test phone usually never shows me the leak trace but I tried it on another phone and it looks like one of my activities is leaking.

Comment: there is some background tasks in that activity thats why its leaking

Answer (score 0):

I found this; I thought I might try it

This is working as expected.
We can't know if a leak is excluded prior to performing the heap dump and analysis. Once we've done that, the default behavior is to display a notification with [Excluded] as a prefix. This lets users know that LeakCanary is done. If there was no feedback at all, you wouldn't have any way to know whether leak canary is done or not. This is arguably a better user experience than no feedback at all.

You can customize this behavior by providing your own subclass of com.squareup.leakcanary.AbstractAnalysisResultService rather than using the default com.squareup.leakcanary.DisplayLeakService

Answer (score 0):

For older LeakCanary, before `v2.0`, try:

```
 /**
 * Excluding known memory leaks from third party libraries
 * @return
 */
protected RefWatcher installLeakCanary() {
    if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
        return RefWatcher.DISABLED;
    } else {

        // IGNORE References: Update or add reference class and context name in instanceField
        ExcludedRefs excludedRefs = AndroidExcludedRefs.createAppDefaults()
                .instanceField("com.example.third.party.TheirClassOne", "context")
                .instanceField("com.example.third.party.TheirClassTwo", "context")
                .build();

        LeakCanary.enableDisplayLeakActivity(this);
        ServiceHeapDumpListener heapDumpListener = new ServiceHeapDumpListener(this, DisplayLeakService.class);
        final RefWatcher refWatcher = LeakCanary.androidWatcher(this, heapDumpListener, excludedRefs);
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
                //IGNORE Activities: Update or add the class name here to ingore the memory leaks from those actvities
                if (activity instanceof ThirdPartyOneActivity) return;
                if (activity instanceof ThirdPartyTwoActivity) return;
                if (activity instanceof ThirdPartyThreeActivity) return;
                refWatcher.watch(activity);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }
        });
        return refWatcher;
    }
}
```